# How to use SQL query with python using PYODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, subquery, pyodbc

I have python script that is connected to **SQL server database** using **streamlit** to create user interface.
One of the query that i use includes **subquery** to select from 2 tables where it goes like this :
the user select a value (coutry name) from a dropdown list and the **query select the name of the country from table A that is =  to the id of the name from table B**

**I guess the error is in the subquery**

code:

```
nationality_stb =  st.selectbox("Select  Country ",rows_NA1,key = "n1" )

    sql = (
    r"select *, "
    r"(select NewColumn from nationality n where n.ID = m.nationality_1 and n.NewColumn = ? OR  ? = ' ' )as first_nationality  "
    r"from dbo.info m "
    r"where "
           
           r"(m.name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL) AND "
           r"(m.nickname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL)"
     param1 = name_search
     param2 = nickname_search
     param3 = nationality_stb                       
     
     rows = cursor.execute(sql, [
                                param1, param1,
                                param2, param2,
                                param3, param3
                                ]).fetchall()
```

EDIT the query with Join:

```
sql = ('''select m.[ID]
                ,m.name
             
          FROM dbo.info m
          inner join 
                    nationality n
          on 
          n.ID = m.nationality_1
          where 
               n.NewColumn = ? OR  ? = ' '
          ;''')
          param3 = nationality_stb
          rows = cursor.execute(sql,[
                                     param3,param3
                                     ]).fetchall()                    
                           
testdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description])
st.write(testdf)
```

i try this query on the sql management studio with  ID = 9  NewColumn = "algeria"

- **return result  = 0**
- **expected return result  = 2**

Comment: And what is that error? Though like I mentioned in your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70326415/how-to-use-sql-with-python-with-pyodbc#comment124316897_70326415), you should probably be using a `JOIN`.

Comment: yes i notice your comment  thanks  i did not know what is the error but it **return nothing** 
so its not possible to use subquery and how to convert this subquery into join with getting the same result ?

Comment: It's possible, just that a `JOIN` would make more sense. As for why your getting no rows, that'll be because no rows match the parameters you entered. With no sample data, expected results, nor the parameters you're inputting, we can't reproduce that.

Comment: no i tried this query in SQL management studio and it return the correct result 
**2 records**...
usually i use   sub query  because it make  more sense to me.
  How to convert this subquery to join

Comment: Queries don't return different results because they are run in different applications like that. Either the queries are the not the same, or you're using it against a different database. I would likely suggest the former, and you are using different values for your parameters.

Comment: Missing parenthesis, should be `n.ID = m.nationality_1 (and n.NewColumn = ? OR  ? = ' ')`. Also in Python you can use a multiline string with `"""`

Comment: @Charlieface i tried to use `"""`  but it display the below error:

`(m.nickname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL);''')
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Comment: @Larnu i did change the question and add the query with **join** and  using `"""`

but still return nothing where as in the sql management it return the correct answer